# How to optimise a boolean expression

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, decision-trees

I am working on an optimization problem involving Boolean expressions and wanted some help as I have very little knowledge about the topic.
The problem statement is as follows:

There are a set of functions, say, f1 to fn outputting either 0 or 1 only and three Boolean operations, AND, OR and NOT, a logical expression involving the functions is expected to be generated as follows:

F1 or F2 and F3 or ………. [ The logical expression need not necessarily include all n variables, n is expected to be ~10].

The logical expression generated is expected to generate a true or false signal, which drives the functioning of a black box. The “success” of the logical expression is measurable by a metric, however, apart from the metric, no other data is readily available from the black box.

Furthermore, the following is expected regarding the nature of the solutions [though not entirely confident]:

1. Vast majority of the solutions is expected to have a negative
   metric, optimal solution is to have a positive metric.
2. Majority of solutions are expected to have a metric close to zero,
   the metric of the best solution is also anticipated to be close to
   zero, but marginally positive.
3. Multiple optimal solutions are anticipated, however variation
   between the metric for the optimal solutions is not anticipated to
   be very large.

Is there a way to find an optimal logical rule that gives the “best” measured performance of the black box?

Comment: If it’s finite you can probably brute-force it and then reduce the winning expression at the end with a karnaugh map or something if I understand this right

Comment: Bruteforcing is expected to take way too long particularly with larger n. Though any help in reducing the problem is appreciated.Could you explain the karnaugh map a bit more?

Comment: Karnaugh maps are just for situations when you have any expression made out of a set of propositions and any combination of ‘and’, ‘or’, and ‘not’ on top of it. Basically the Karnaugh map is just a big discrete state space (like a truth table) for every different possible combination of the propositions being true or false, but laid out in a particular way such that you can build a new, far simpler version of the same expression by identifying rectangular “clumps” in the Karnaugh map. I kind of can’t explain it too well through text but it’s basically a tool for finding the minimal form

Comment: Okay. That deals with simplification of expression but not exactly with finding the optimal one. I would still have to evaluate out the possible combinations, albeit, a possibly reduced sample space.